# How do I change a trigger fucntion in mysql to postgresql trigger

Tags: postgresql, triggers, plpgsql

I have a trigger function in MySQL written as such:

```
CREATE TRIGGER after_customers_insert
BEFORE INSERT
ON customers FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
SET @created := (SELECT IFNULL(created_at, NOW()) FROM customers ORDER BY created_at 
DESC LIMIT 1);

IF YEAR(@created) <> YEAR(NEw.created_at) THEN
   SET NEW.Newid :=  1;
ELSE
    SET NEW.Newid := (SELECT IFNULL(MAX(Newid),0) + 1 FROM customers);
END IF;
SET NEW.custom_id = CONCAT('KR_',DATE_FORMAT(now(), '%y'),'_',LPAD(NEW.Newid,3,'0'));
END
```

I tried to convert in Postgres this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION after_customers_insert()
RETURNS trigger AS
$BODY$
BEGIN
SET @created := (SELECT IFNULL(created_at, NOW()) FROM customers ORDER BY created_at DESC LIMIT 1);

IF YEAR(@created) <> YEAR(NEw.created_at) THEN
   SET NEW.Newid :=  1;
ELSE
    SET NEW.Newid := (SELECT IFNULL(MAX(Newid),0) + 1 FROM customers);
END IF;
SET NEW.custom_id = CONCAT('KR_',DATE_FORMAT(now(), '%y'),'_',LPAD(NEW.Newid,3,'0'));
END
$BODY$
LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
COST 100;
```

but without success. Any help please??

Comment: Don't expect others to do all the work for you. First, try to do something yourself, show the code that you got in the transformation process, show the compiler error and you will get an answer.

Comment: See [Create trigger](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createtrigger.html) and [plpgsql trigger function](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-trigger.html)

Comment: Why do you think this is valid code for PostgreSQL, where did you found examples like that?

Comment: @FrankHeikens can you any help?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is just a code request, not a request for fixing a bug or so. He could hire a programmer if he needs one

Comment: The relevant parts of the PL/pgSQL reference [Assignment](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-ASSIGNMENT), [declare block](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-structure.html) [Executing a Command with a Single-Row Result](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-SQL-ONEROW) and [Date/Time functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-datetime.html) will help as well

Comment: Generating a new ID using `select max()` is a horrible idea and is guaranteed to give duplicates when concurrent transactions insert data.